# Как закрепить сообщение в теме / топике телеграм чата?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Пишу бота на python-telegram-bot v20, интересует возможность закрепления сообщения в конкретном топике супер чата.
Так понял `pin_chat_message()` не имеет аргумента `message_thread_id`, возможно есть какие то ещё способы или костыли для реализации такой функции?

Пробовал передавать id топика с id чата, `to_topic_mes = f'{chat_id}/{topic_id}'`, но очевидно способ не сработал, так как `to_topic_mes` заменят только id чата и получается `https://t.me/c/to_topic_mes/1/`, а необходимо что бы получилось `https://t.me/c/chat_id/topic_id/`
Возможно ли как то это реализовать?
Интересуют любые возможные варианты, можно на другой библиотеке или, если возможно, на другом языке